# System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, exception, .net, pdf-writer

At attempt to write PDF document with following code:

```
document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = null; ;
try
{
    writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"E:\mergFiles", FileMode.Create));
}
catch (Exception xc)
{ }
```

I am getting an exception:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\mergFiles' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at PDFLibrary.PDFManager.MergeDocs()}
```

I have all access to this folder.

goggled and found that this could help `File.SetAttributes(@"E:\mergFiles", FileAttributes.Normal);` but still I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: `mergFiles` sounds like a directory, not a single file. So I wouldn't expect it to be passed to a `FileStream` constructor.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that "E:\mergFiles" is file name (as code says), and not folder as text in your post says?

Comment: it is the name of a folder

Comment: So what do you want - you can't have file name and folder name to be identical - make a decision and adjust code to avoid collision. Consider using helper from `Path` class to create path...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can't pass the name of a folder to a `FileStream`. It needs to be a file name including the path (**edit**: of course it doesn't really *have* to include the path if you use a relative file name).

If you want to create a folder, use `Directory.CreateDirectory`. To create a file within that folder, use something like this:

```
string fullName = Path.Combine(pathName, fileName);
writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: I see this error  'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' .